# HTTP Error 500.31 - ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies .Net Core 2.2

Tags: c#, .net, web, asp.net-core

mi problema es que tenia funcionando una aplicación con .Net Core 2.2 en IIS (Versión 10, windows 10), intente montar otro desarrollo también creado con .Net Core 2.2, por error desinstale el runtime que tenia funcionando bien, el caso es que ahora mi nueva aplicación funciona en el IIS sin problemas mientras que la primera aplicación no funciona con IIS, me da error HTTP Error 500.31.

- Cosas que he intentado, quite la nueva aplicación del IIS para dejarlo como estaba.
- Instale el .net core 2.2 en la última versión disponible, tanto el SDK como el Hosting Bundle, de hecho instalo la 3.0 y la 3.1 y nada igual no funciona, se que el tener versiones superiores puede que de conflictos por lo que también las he instalado solas una por una pero igual ya no funciona.

Actualmente lo que tengo instalado es:

---

---

> SDK de .NET Core (reflejando cualquier global.json):  Version:
>   3.1.100  Commit:    cd82f021f4
>
> Entorno de tiempo de ejecución:  OS Name:     Windows  OS Version: 
>   10.0.18362  OS Platform: Windows  RID:         win10-x64  Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.100\
>
> Host (useful for support):   Version: 3.1.1   Commit:  a1388f194c
>
> .NET Core SDKs installed:
>     2.2.204 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
>     2.2.207 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
>     3.0.102 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
>     3.1.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
>
> .NET Core runtimes installed:   Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.14
>   [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.5 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.8 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.14 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.5 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.8 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.2 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.0 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
>   2.1.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.5 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
>   2.2.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.2 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
>   3.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.1 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>   Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.0.2 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
>   Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.0 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
>   Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.1 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
>
> To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
>   https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

---

---

Con esta configuración si pongo la nueva si funciona, luego la quito y pongo la vieja aplicación y no funciona sigue el 500.31.

Gracias de antemano a quien pueda responder.

Comment: Podrías poner el resultado que te devuelve al ejecutar este comando en consola:
*dotnet --list-sdks* y también este: *dotnet --list-runtimes*:
Por lo que pones en tu pregunta, quizás has quitado el runtime que se necesita.
Si quieres, puedes tener más de un runtime instalado a la vez.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Sebastian, no tengo claro aún si debo tener solo el runtime que necesito o si puedo tener varios instalados? al parecer lo que entiendo es que si estoy usando el .Net Core 2.X puedo tener solo sus variantes (2.0, 2.1, 2.2 etc.) es lo que creo, aunque no estoy seguro de esto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución que realicé fue la de tomar un respaldo que tenia de mi aplicación e irle incorporando todas las vistas, controladores, modelos, también los css y js que había modificado y me funciono bien. No se que habría cambiado pero lo mas seguro es que actualice algo y esto desconfiguro mi aplicación con el SDK que estoy usando que es el 2.2.